# array slicing for convolutional block

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, deep-learning

I get confused by a array slicing notation.

```
def hypernetwork(self, inputs):
    x = self.fc(inputs)

    return x[..., :self.channels], x[..., self.channels:]
```

what is the return? what does `...,` mean? The `self.channels` is defined as the number of channels of the input. I think `x` is just the input feature block. Below is the relevant code for `self.fc` and `self.channels`

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.channels = input_shape[0][-1]  # input_shape: [x, z].

    self.fc = KL.Dense(
        int(2 * self.channels),
        kernel_initializer=self.init,
        kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(
            l=self.wt_decay,
        ),
        bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(
            l=self.wt_decay,
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to all the dimensions except the last one (which you are slicing) when using `...`. It is equivalent to the other notation `x[:, :, :channels]`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(111)
channels = 2
x = tf.random.normal((1, 2, 3))
print(x)
print(x[..., :channels], x[:, :, :channels]) # Equivalent
print(x[..., channels:], x[:, :, channels:]) # Equivalent
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.7558127   1.5447265   1.6315602 ]
  [-0.19868968  0.08828261  0.01711658]]], shape=(1, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.7558127   1.5447265 ]
  [-0.19868968  0.08828261]]], shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.7558127   1.5447265 ]
  [-0.19868968  0.08828261]]], shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[1.6315602 ]
  [0.01711658]]], shape=(1, 2, 1), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(
[[[1.6315602 ]
  [0.01711658]]], shape=(1, 2, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: forgot to reply your answer. It is very useful. I got the meaning of the expresssion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`...` means all elements of all dimensions until you start explicitely referencing, which you do with the `:self.channels`.
So in conclusion if `x` is e.g. a 10x4x6 array and `self.channels` is 4, the output will be one 10x4x4 array and one 10x4x2 array.
If `x` is 10x6 and `self.channels` is 2, you'll get a 10x2 and a 10x4 array. You're splitting the array along the last dimension.